# password_verify returns false if i fetch the hash from db but returns true if i copy and paste it

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, hash, bcrypt

So after putting the password in my database
( column password is type binary(255) )

```
//let's say his username is on $username and password in $password
$password = "abc123";
$con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES(:usr,:psw)";
$stmt->bindValue( "usr", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$newpsw = password_hash ( $password , PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$stmt->bindValue( "psw", $newpsw, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->execute();
```

through cmd i go to the database and i can see that the password is this

```
$2y$10$nDzlRwWfC9sTvVqv5f7G1eByHethRHjEWGwBOjkpoaq3y2Fb.LCC.
```

now when the user logs in i succesfully retrieve his password from the database

```
//let's say his username is on $username and password in $password
$con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = :usr LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindValue( "usr", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();
$psw_from_db = $result["password"]; //checked with echo and it's correct
```

If i do

`password_verify($password , $psw_from_db);`

it will return false although i checked both $password and $psw_from_db
and they have the correct values inside.

If i copy the password directly from the database and place it instead of $psw_from_db it will return true

```
password_verify($password ,'$2y$10$nDzlRwWfC9sTvVqv5f7G1eByHethRHjEWGwBOjkpoaq3y2Fb.LCC.');
//'' have to be used, it won't work with ""
```

I'm searching for some hours now but i haven't found the solution.

Comment: Do you get the correct bcrypt hash when you do `var_dump` of `$psw_from_db`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the documentation for [BINARY datatype in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html), it appears that the response you are getting is right padded with `\0` (null character):

> When `BINARY` values are stored, they are right-padded with the pad
>   value to the specified length. The pad value is `0x00` (the zero
>   byte). Values are right-padded with `0x00` on insert, and no trailing
>   bytes are removed on select. All bytes are significant in comparisons,
>   including ORDER BY and DISTINCT operations. `0x00` bytes and spaces
>   are different in comparisons, with `0x00` < space.

Thus, when you retrieve the password from database, you are actually receiving a string of length 255 (which is why I asked for `var_dump` in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593888/password-verify-returns-false-if-i-fetch-the-hash-from-db-but-returns-true-if-i?noredirect=1#comment84191229_48593888), and not `echo`). Testing for a few values locally, I received something like:

```
string(255) "$2y$10$L5C66A5xFvf1YYAoWbnQDuRyveVOrnz1jfV/Eb0kT9UkZlWzCfK8a"
string(255) "$2y$10$EAkfkh8S1m66FWAX/KZYMeuhteDREL5B22cgLP0feKZ9.ydMgcgpa"
string(255) "$2y$10$Ll/272JbvIilDj74FAqVIeckWUGezqT926Z1LkVBZZSVwTaFUGOLe"
string(255) "$2y$10$fxvZv2ya0RncOksp09vqjekIWNmdEX9fEUahU6puSe8HqGcY51re6"
string(255) "$2y$10$f1xDu3fFnqMw.MEa4.93Tu3ouhr3kmXXbe41oTyy8xGTKaRbafQ8G"
string(255) "$2y$10$YhjBmNFjL7a8lj1Soyvdhe9GpfQ7SsX.dfkI0keQ0IgrkKIfQQjpC"
```

You can use [`trim`](https://devdocs.io/php/function.trim) or change the datatype from `BINARY(255)` to `BINARY(60)` or `CHAR(60) BINARY` or even `CHAR(60)` with `latin1` collation. (bcrypt hashes are 59-60 bytes).

Comment: That is the correct answer. I var_dumped multiple values into a variable and then i returned that variable to alert it in javascript but the psw_from_db was the last one and instead of showing extra spaces only the last " was missing.